# Can we charge an object using cathode rays?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, estimation

Can we charge an object using cathode rays and use that to charge to repel and object, which is around 500 grams or so...If yes how many coloumbs of charge will it take?

Answer (score 0):

## Can we charge an object using cathode rays?

Cathode rays are beams of electrons. If you shoot electrons at an object and the electrons stick then yes, this will charge an object because the object has acquired more electrons.

## How many columbs of charge will it take to repel an object?

Technically speaking, just a single electron ($-1.6\times 10^{-19}$ coulombs) is enough to create a repulsive force and therefore "repel" an object. Of course, on human scales, such a tiny repulsive force is usually undetectible. If you want to know how many columns of charge is required to overcome an attractive force then we need to know much more information, like how strong the attractive force is and how far apart the two objects are.